Is it possible to set the initial coefficients of the model in sklearn's LogisticRegression?
Even though recovering the LogisticRegression model coefficients after training is pretty straightforward through the coef_  attribute, custom setting the initial values of the LogisticRegression model coefficients isn't so easy. In fact, I simply couldn't find this anywhere. Is it even possible?
I tried setting the coef_ attribute value directly after instantiating the LogisticRegression class, but it raised a run time error.
